# Consequences of a proof of Schanuel's conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, conjectures, transcendental-numbers

Schanuel's conjecture is a strengthening of the Lindemann-Weierstrass-threorem. It states

> If $\lambda_1,\cdots \lambda_n$ are complex numbers linear independent over $\mathbb Q$, then $$\mathbb Q(\lambda_1,\cdots \lambda_n,e^{\lambda_1},\cdots ,e^{\lambda_n})$$ has transcendental degree at least $n$ over $\mathbb Q$

(See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchanuelsConjecture.html )

I recently read that in transcendental-theory "anything could be proven", if Schanuel's conjecture would be proven.

One of the consequences would be that $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent. In particular, many combinations of $e$ and $\pi$ could be proven to be transcendental, for example $e+\pi$ , $e\pi$ , $e^e$ and so on.
But what could be proven else ?

> Can someone give a survey which type of numbers could be proven to be transcendental ? I would like to get an idea of the power of the conjecture and to understand the "anything" better.

Additional questions :

> Would Schanuel's conjecture be of any use in the case of the Euler-Mascheroni-constant (I guess no) ?
>
> How strong do mathematicians believe that Schanuel's conjecture is true ? Are there any mathematicians having doubts or do some mathematicians even believe it is false ? (My guess is that the conjecture is strongly believed to be true)

Comment: Could you make this more self-contained by telling us what Shanuel's conjecture says? $\qquad$

Comment: I haven't fully digested this yet: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136627/is-%CF%80-definable-in-bbb-r-0-1-%C3%97-exp/136642#136642

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3550

Comment: [Transcendental Numbers](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4939-0832-5.pdf) by M. Ram Murty
Purusottam Rath has a chapter entitled Schanuel’s Conjecture.